# How to remove a bar located under Skype in Start menu

Tags: windows-10, skype

I have a bar that looks like a progress bar under Skype in Windows 10 in the start menu. How do I remove this? I tried to unpin then pin the Skype but it still remains.[image]

I have Windows 10 x64 Home 1803. I use VirtualBox and if I update to 1909/1903 then the VM software crashes due to my laptop, Toshiba, having a bug with these updates.

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you using?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound that information is not actually necessary to answer the question. This behavior will be present in every Windows 10 build.

Comment: I use VirtualBox myself, and I have had a problem that a VM would crash after an upgrade. If you ensure that the VM is properly shutdown, and not in a saved state before you upgrade, and you also ensure that VirtualBox is running the latest version of that brand (latest 5 or 6), and you have the extension pack for that version installed, it should work.

Comment: Yes. The problem is that I get crashes when updating the Linux Kernel. I always shut it down properly. The problem, I was told, is with my laptop's manufacturer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bar you are seeing is an indicator that an app is being updated. Skype in your case is an app, and it is being updated. It is possible the update is paused or corrupted.

If you go to start, settings, apps and then scroll down to Skype, you should see the same progress bar. If you click on advanced options, you should be able to reset the app, which clears all data and reïnstalls the app. This should solve any stagnent update.

Alternatively, you can choose to remove, and then reïnstall it from the Windows Store, but this should not be necessary for you and I would definitely use this method as a last resort.